# How to crop an image with no user interaction in android?

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to crop a  picture but I don't want any user interaction or intent or some activity...  So is there a function I can just pass the image object, cordinates  where to crop as parameters and get the cropped image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use `createBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) on `Bitmap`.